Get Page URl when changing slug and permalink
Need to get page URL programmatically as client changes the slug and permalink from time to time.
I tried below using permalink but this cannot be used because of the above mentioned issue,
$baseUrl = home_url('/price/');


edit your question to show us the code your tried.

can you add some context to explain what you're asking better and what the problem you're trying to solve is? Your question is not very clear and confusing. Use the Edit link underneath the list of tags to modify the question to make it easier to understand. I've made a few edits to try and make it easier to read and replace some words I suspect were incorrectly used

Instead of hardcoding the slug, instead store the ID in an option and then use it to call get_permalink(). You can also avoid hardcoding the $baseUrl and rely on a nav menu or button block instead so that it automatically updates.
For example,
$page_id = .....; // maybe a `get_option` call or something else? Depends where you want to store the ID of the page
$baseUrl = get_permalink( $page_id );

In general, avoid storing URLs slugs or URL fragments, and don't put "magic values" such as numebers and strings in your PHP code.

If we need a specific page URL, we have to hard code the page id right?

how is created this page ? e.g. if it's done by the plugin, the creation code get the page id and can be stored as said by Tom J Nowell.

I wouldn't hardcode the page ID, if the page is deleted and recreated it would break, you'll need to store the page ID somewhere in the database and retrieve it, this also means you'll need a UI for setting it. Judging from the code you shared though there's probably a better way to do this as it looks like you're manually constructing URLs in PHP by joining strings together which is not good. What is this for?

I have a facet-filtered page, and there's a button on another page. When this button is clicked, it needs to route to the facet-filtered page and activate a relevant filter. To achieve this, I need to retrieve the URL of the facet-filtered page in order to create an anchor link.
